# Why do Kafka consumer need to be stopped if commit fails?

Tags: apache-kafka

If the Kafka consumer read a message from TOPIC. Try to process the message but are unable to commit the completion of the processing(due to network issue or commit took more time due to some other resource issue), then message what is the state of the consumer?

Tried starting consumer with consumerWrapper(concurrency with 1), but when the commit failed, the consumer went down too along with the exception.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

There was no way to throw the exception or communicate the same to the client.

Comment: Please show your stacktrace of what exception you're referring to

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.